# Viber contacts out of date - not all contacts displayed in "All" tab

Tags: contacts, viber-messenger

My address book is not Google Contacts, but [Local Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.psencik.simple). All of my contacts belong to it. [Viber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip) sees many of my contacts as Viber-enabled from LocalSync. However, I'm sure that it's missing some of them.

By simply going to Viber's "All" contacts tab I see missing entries. These entries appear in stock `Contacts` app. Viber is up to date to the latest version. These people told me that they have Viber and I can get calls from them (however they are detected as `Unknown`)

How can I let Viber actually see all contacts in my address book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an official representative of Viber Media.

The source of this issue could greatly vary. Please [read this short page in our HelpDesk](http://helpme.viber.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/67/13/android-contact-list-is-not-showing-your-friends-as-viber-users), <sup>quoted below</sup> outlining some possible workarounds that will help reboot synchronization of the contact list:

> ## Android: Contact list is not showing your friends as Viber users?
>
> Make sure you are using the latest version of Viber. You can download the latest version from http://www.viber.com/
>
> Make sure that you are looking at the Viber contact list, not your device's contact list.
>
> In order for your contacts to see you as a Viber user and be able to call you through Viber, your phone number, which is saved on their address book, must be the exact same number that you used to register to Viber and vice- versa.
>
> Try tapping on the 'More' tab at the bottom of the Viber app, then select "Settings" and the add a check mark [√]  to "Show all Contacts"
>
> Once you installed Viber, if you do not see someone in your contact list whom you know to have Viber, it might be that the list is not updated (this may be due to an unstable connection during setup, or just a slight delay). To update your contact list, re-sync it by re-initiating Viber or by manually updating your contacts list.
>
> You don't need to uninstall and reinstall Viber. Shut Viber down (so that it no longer runs in the background) or turn the phone off, and then re-open it.
>
> If this does not work, try the following steps:
>
> 1. Send the user an invite and if the number is a registered Viber user, it will automatically update the Viber contact list.
> 2. Enter into your Viber contact list, then select the device's menu button, and tap on "update contacts". Then just click your device 'home' button. Viber will run in the background. In about 30 min. to an hour, check again by clicking on the Viber icon.
> 3. Confirm that you have an active internet connection.
> 4. Dial a number manually, using the Viber keypad
> 5. Delete the contact with the missing Viber badge from your contact list. Add it again and make sure to include the country code.
>
> The phone number format should include the plus sign, country code, cell code and phone number. The standard format is: +(country code)-(cell code)-(phone number)
>
> For example: +1-555-555-5555

---

For more questions or technical support, please visit our official HelpDesk.

## From the FAQ:

Try tapping on the "More" tab at the bottom of the Viber app, then select "Settings" and the add a check mark [√]  to "Show all Contacts".

Comment: Thanks for providing an official response. Note, please, that answers at Stack Exchange should be self-contained. Should you change your KB system and render this link inoperative this answer will have no value. Stack Exchange is built on the idea of helping many people in the future and not just the one person who asked the question.

Comment: I edited the answer with "the answer" I found on the FAQs. I confirm it worked. Please peer accept my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a simliar problem, where a certain person did not appear on viber (in the All tab), however I'm using the stock application all around.
It was solved by changing the group assigned to the contact (originally it had no group assigned, and I assigned it to my contacts).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that a contact is recognized when I remove it from all contact groups. When I add the contact back to a group, it disappears again in Viber.
So this is a rather unpleasant workaround, but technically it would work (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

for solve this problem which worked for me:

1. Go To Viber Setting
2. Press Restore Viber Defaults
3. Do This 3 Or 4 Times
4. Restart Your Device
5. Do It Again

Should be fine now